# Conversion of commands from PBS to SLURM

Tags: linux, slurm, pbs

What is the equivalent of

```
qmgr -c "print queue UCTlong"
```

in Slurm?

PS: the command up there displays all the characteristics of the queue "UCTlong" (max walltime, max running jobs, ....).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slurm uses the word 'partition' rather than queue. The command would be

```
scontrol show partition UCTlong
```